# Avoid newline when using raiserror

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, output, raiserror

Suppose I debug using `raiserror`, like so:

```
raiserror('Trying to do something...',0,0) with nowait

(queries that do something)

raiserror('Done.',0,0) with nowait
```

It would be handy to have this output in the "Messages" of SSMS in a single line:

`Trying to do something...Done.`

Is there a way? I haven't found anything around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, either you wait until both actions are complete and print a single line with one call, or you have the output on two lines. SSMS (and ADS) just aren’t equipped to do what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe a dirty hack to remove the last line from there?

Comment: Since the tools don't have this feature, the solution is a custom app or PowerShell script.

Comment: @George Sure, write a custom add-in that manipulates the text in the messages pane. Sounds like a fun project, but nothing I know of that already exists.